# One of my variables in one of my classes "cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: java, eclipse, object, inheritance, static

Here's my class Person.java (simplified to remove text I think is unrelated to the problem):

```
public class Person {
    int myIdNumber;
    String myName;
    String myBirthday;
    String myType;
    Person(String forTheName, int forTheId, String forTheBirthday, String forTheType){
        this.myIdNumber = forTheId;
        this.myName = forTheName;
        this.myBirthday = forTheBirthday;
        this.myType = forTheType;
    }
}
```

And here's PersonAdd.java (likewise simplified):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class PersonAdd {
    public static int numOfPeople = 0;
    static String instruction = "Enter the person's ";
    static String theName;
    static String theBirthday;
    static String theType;
    static void entryText(){
        numOfPeople++;
        theName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, instruction + "name.", "Add People", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);         
        theBirthday = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, instruction + "birthday.", "Add People", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        theType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, instruction + "type.", "Add People", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            entryText();
            Object person1 = new Person(theName, numOfPeople, theBirthday, theType);
            entryText();
            Object person2 = new Person(theName, numOfPeople, theBirthday, theType);
            entryText();
            Object person3 = new Person(theName, numOfPeople, theBirthday, theType);
            String response = person1.myName;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response);
        }
    }
```

The expected result is for the last dialog box to display the name given, but it's not working, although I believe it is storing the data entered correctly. The key problem is in the line

```
String response = person1.myName;
```

which cannot be resolved or is not a field. It also happens if I add a get method and use that instead of myName. Eclipse doesn't even seem to be able to see any of the objects of person1.

I'm sure this has to do with my failure to understand inheritance, or static/non-static, or something. (This class-and-object stuff is especially tricky for me to grasp; I think in "SQL mode" and want to be able to say something like "select-from-where".)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've declared your variable as type `Object` which is the base type of every reference type, ie. it's the parent class of your `Person` class.

You can therefore only access fields and methods available through the [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) type.

You'll need to declare your variable as type `Person`

```
Person person1 = new Person(...);
```

or cast the variable before you use it

```
String response = ((Person) person1).myName;
```

---

Also, be careful with your [access modifiers.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Ah, thank you! I believe I'm still in a mental mode where data types feel so "official" that I sometimes forget I am basically creating new ones myself when I create classes with constructor methods, and that of course it's "okay" to refer to entities of a custom data type.